# I can't change race in a custom game

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-5

When I create a random map in `Custom game` menu, I can not change the race when I play on this map.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the "random towns" option when generating the map (at the bottom). Otherwise all towns will get a fixed race and as such each player will be bound to that race.

Comment: do you know how I can set up teams? When I generate a map with 3 players, I can not change their team color and it is FFA, but I want to make teams.